# movie15 - not show on the PDF

Tags: beamer, movie15

Not working?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{movie15}
 \usepackage{graphics}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{polish}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{Simulation}
 \begin{picture}(320,300)
 \put(0,80){\includemovie[poster, text={\small(Loading 11.mp4)}]{9cm}{6cm}{11.mp4}}
 \put(90,260){Rotating sine}
 \end{picture}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

and

```
\begin{frame}{Filmy *.avi}  
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{block}{}
\small
Symulacja 
\end{block}
\end{column}\pause \
\begin{column}{4.2cm}
\begin{block}{}
\includemovie[autoplay,repeat]{4cm}{3cm}{11.mp4}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which PDF viewer have you tried, I don't think movies works in most viewer, except Adobe Reader.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

According to Movie15 documentations you need to compile twice in order to be able to playback well the movie, and like the comments say that will only work on acrobat reader and maybe oKular

Comment: Well, it compile does not show anything, only empty frame of movie window.